# My app show splash screen every time i tap home screen icon while app in background

Tags: android

I am developing an android app but there is a problem

- When I press home button from my device navigation when the app is show in the 
  display it's gone background
- but when I tap app icon from home screen then every time it shows
  splash screen first and then takes me to wherever(activity) I left
  last
- if I start the app from the recent task then it doesn't show me
  splash screen and directly take me to wherever(activity) I left.

here Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.videowatermark.addtextandtimestampongalleryvideos">
    <!-- In App Billing permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" /> <!-- Network permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> <!-- Location Permisssion -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <!-- Storage Permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- System Overlay Window -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" /> <!-- Restart of Devcie -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> <!-- Audio setting -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> <!-- Tell the system this app requires OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".AutoStamperApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/autologo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/autologo"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.StampedVideoListAct"
            android:label="@string/stamped_video"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <service
            android:name=".services.StampOnVideoService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/Video_Gallery_Stamper_APP_ID" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.AutoStamperActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.InAppBillingActivity"
            android:label="@string/txt_inapp_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.OfferActivity"
            android:label="@string/offer_activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.InternalBrowserActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/about-us"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/terms-and-condition"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/privacy-policy"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/date-and-time-stamp"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/signature-stamp"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/gps"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/watermark-logo"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.autostamper.us"
                    android:path="/*"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".services.VideoStampingService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post manifest configurations

Comment: check now I updated question

Comment: did you  try setting `NoHistory=true` for splash activity?

Comment: it's not working. anything else?

Comment: let me see, checking it...

Comment: Your splash screen cal every time when you open home screen it means you do not make splash screen as your Main activity

Answer (score 1):

Please remove below line from your splash activity tag

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```